# React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing

I'm looking for solution. I have form that validate user input and display error, if input is not provided. Then, during manual testing, when input is provided, the errors disappear, however I cannot reproduce the correct behavior in my tests.

I have tried both .not.toBeInDocument and .not.toBeVisible() + wrap the state update into act()

Component code:

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  nickname: yup.string().required("Nickname is required"),
  password: yup.string().required("Password is required"),
});
export default function LoginForm() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({ resolver: yupResolver(schema) });
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Inputs> = (data) => console.log(data);

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <FormControl>
        <Label htmlFor="nickname">Username:</Label>
        <InputText
          placeholder="Nickname"
          id="nickname"
          {...register("nickname")}
        ></InputText>
        {errors.nickname?.message && (
          <ErrorText data-testid="error">{errors.nickname?.message}</ErrorText>
        )}
      </FormControl>
      <FormControl>
        <Label htmlFor="password">Password:</Label>
        <InputText
          placeholder="Password"
          id="password"
          type="password"
          {...register("password", { required: true })}
        ></InputText>
        {errors.password?.message && (
          <ErrorText data-testid="error">{errors.password?.message}</ErrorText>
        )}
      </FormControl>
      <FormControl>
        <SubmitButton type="submit" value="Login"></SubmitButton>
      </FormControl>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

The test:

```
  test("Correct input does not give error anymore", async () => {
    render(
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <LoginForm />
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
    const button = screen.getByDisplayValue(/Login/i);
    fireEvent.click(button);
    const usernameInput = screen.getByLabelText(/username:/i);
    const passwordInput = screen.getByLabelText(/password:/i);
    act(() => {
      fireEvent.change(usernameInput, { target: { value: "test123" } });
      fireEvent.change(passwordInput, { target: { value: "123456" } });
    });
    const errors = await screen.findAllByTestId("error");
    expect(usernameInput.value).toBe("test123");
    expect(passwordInput.value).toBe("123456");
    expect(errors[1]).not.toBeInTheDocument();

    expect(errors[0]).not.toBeVisible();
  });
```

FireEvent.click() creates an errors "lorem is required". The problem is that fireEvent change does not change the error message, the console prints:

```
Received: <span class="sc-iBPTik eglsQB" data-testid="error">Nickname is required</span>
```

So I tried to reproduce manual testing without success.

Comment: Try `expect(screen.queryByText('my error text')).toBeNull()`. Also, check out the userEvent library instead of fireEvent. It is much easier to fill out input forms.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing for something that - according to the unit test - does not exist.

The following line illustrates that.

```
 {
   errors.password?.message && (
      <ErrorText data-testid="error">
        {errors.password?.message}
      </ErrorText>
   )
  }
```

The line above says that if there are no errors then don't render this. And if there are then render this.
Since there are no elements of `<ErrorText />` being rendered then there will not be any elements in the document with the attribute of `data-testid="error"`

If you add this in your test file below where you defined `errors`:

```
console.log(errors)
```

Then you should see an empty array logged in the terminal.

I've always found unit testing validation errors tricky.

What I prefer to do is disable a button related to the form based on whether the input values are supplied.

You can then check whether the button is enabled by doing something like this:

```
    const button = getByText('Submit');
    expect(button).toBeEnabled();
```

Comment: My main motivation to create this question was that I recieve this console log
`
    expect(element).not.toBeInTheDocument()

    expected document not to contain element, found <span class="sc-iBPTik eglsQB" data-testid="error">Password is required</span> instead
`